# Removing duplicates from multiple directories(more than 2 paths) using rmlint or another tool

Tags: linux, deduplication, rmlint

I am trying to remove duplicated files and folders from several directories, and I was wondering if rmlint supports inputting multiple directories (I know you can use two directories if one of them is set as the reference). If not, have anyone found a fast and efficient cli tool to go through large directories?

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: I cleaned it up. Basically, I can use `rmlint dir1 dir2, dir3` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to invoke `rmlint` with multiple input directories:

```
rmlint dir1 dir2 dir3
```

`rmlint` will generate a shell script that you can then execute to perform the deletion:

```
./rmlint.sh
```

Comment: Can it also invoke multiple reference directories?